# Android read from internal path

Tags: android

I copied a file into a path(tried /storage/self/primary/ and /sdcard/) using adb, this file have rwxrwx--x permissions.

Then I tried to read it from an android application using the following code

```
try{
    RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("path to fle", "r");
    String line = "";

    while((line = raf.readLine()) != null){
        Log.v("y", line);
    }
    raf.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("smth", "..............." + e.getMessage());
}
```

but I get `open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` I also tried chmod +w on the specified files.

What should I do(putting the file into the res folder is not a solution because I need to read it this way as I'm using a library that I can't modify).

Observation:
I have a Nexus 5, Android 6.0.1

Thank you!

Comment: Why did you chmod +w? That is the write permission

Comment: @Ionut Cosmin Mihai : I think you don't have storage permission make sure  you have read write storage permission defined in Android Mainifest + ask for Storage permission from OS < as in Android 6 storage permission kept in danger level >

Comment: I puted <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> in the manifest but it doesn't work.